# .Net core startup base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Wishing to use .Net core to create a suite of micro services, I was thinking of creating a base class for the Startup class which would be responsible for configuring common features such as logging, authentication, endpoint health checks therefore standardizing all our services.

I was surprised however that such a pattern does not seem to be mentioned. Is the preferred pattern to use custom middleware for common functionality instead? Any thoughts or experience in relation to this dilemma would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Create extensions methods for `IServiceCollection` and/or `IApplicationBuilder` interfaces in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAllCoolStuff(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    services.AddSingleton<FooService>();
    services.AddTransient<IBooService, BooService>();
    ...

    return services;
}

public static IApplicationBuilder UseAllCoolStuff(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }

    app.UseMiddleware<SomeCoolMiddleware>();
    ...

    return app;
}
```

And use them in your Startup's:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAllCoolStuff();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseAllCoolStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IStartup interface or the StartupBase class if you really wish to do this. I have done the same so that all microservices have the same configuration making it easier to manage as we have lots of microservices.

See:
https://www.strathweb.com/2017/06/resolving-asp-net-core-startup-class-from-the-di-container/

And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.startupbase?view=aspnetcore-2.0

The source code for StartupBase can be seen at:
https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Startup/StartupBase.cs

The following is the IStartup interface:

```
public interface IStartup
{
    IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);

    void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app);
}
```

And an example of how you would use it:

```
public class Startup : IStartup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        var loggerFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

        // Set up application pipeline
    }
}
```